# How to programmatically create new user with custom fields?

Tags: 7, users

I want to create user with some custom fields. I have created extra fields through config > people > site information > manage fields and fields like first name, last name, city etc. I want to create user with this custom fields.

**How can I create user programmatically?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using [`user_save`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) Drupal function you can create new users like so:

```
$new_user = array(
  'name' => 'JohnDoe',
  'mail' => 'john.doe@email.com',
  'pass' => 'password123',
  'status' => 1,
  'field_custom_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => 'John'))), // This becomes $account->field_custom_first_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']
  'field_custom_last_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => 'Doe'))),
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
  'roles' => array(), // No other roles than Authenticated
  //'roles' => array('10' => '10', '11' => '11'), // If you want to specify additional roles, the numbers are role_id's
);
user_save(NULL, $new_user);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `access` does, I've copied this from the user_save page's comments on d.o and modified them, so I'm not 100% on what `access` does. I'm gonna assume that it's the last access date, so if it's a new user, I'm guessing it shouldn't be set.

Comment: thanks its working good for me. and sorry for late replay.

Comment: @GandhiPranav Don't forget to accept the answers to your questions if they've helped you out; this lets future visitors know that a particular solution was the one that solved your specific problem, and it rewards the answerer for their efforts. You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark underneath the vote indicator. Thanks :)

Comment: Access is just the last access field (like the "created" field

Comment: This works to create new users, but isn't there a "preferred" entity way like with nodes? Something involving entity_create_stub_entity('user') or entity_metadata_wrapper(..)?  I ask because I have been struggling doing it the entity way.. :)

Comment: @texas-bronius see here: https://devblog.more-onion.com/content/snippet-how-programmatically-create-user-profile2-using-entity-api (not sure if it works or not)