# How to create a user with custom fields?

Tags: 8, users, database

On my drupal site, using the User module, I have added extra fields to the user registration form such as 'Organization'. I notice that this has created a mysql database called 'user__field_organization'.

I am trying to write a custom module which involves creating new users.

At the moment my module creates a new user, with a username, password and email.
The code for this (which works fine) is:

```
$user_data = ['name' => 'John', 'mail' => 'email@me.co.uk', 'pass' => 'examplePassword','status' => 1,]; 

$this->user = $this->user_store->create($user_data);
```

(where `$this->user_store = $etm->getStorage('user');` )

But I also need to update the extra fields such as Organization but can't work out how to do this.

I have looked at this question: [How to programmatically create new user with custom fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69694/how-to-programmatically-create-new-user-with-custom-fields)

And I have tried adding `custom_field_organization` or `user__field_organization` into `$user_data` but it doesn't work.

I have been trying to find out where in the User module a user is created once the registration form is submitted. If I could find that then I could copy what is done there.

Comment: You should be able to set that just using field_organization. If that doesn't work (it should though), you can set the value by doing things like $user->field_organization = $value. You can see the machine name of the fields in the configuration page for the user entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the right solution. You have to add `'field_organization' => 'some_value'` to your `$user_data` array.

They keys in the $user_data array is the field names. The field name is what comes after `user__` in the table name. You can also see the field name in the UI where you add the fields (it’s also called machine name).